# java can not read a line from file

Tags: java, java-8, eof, unexpectendoffile

I'm reading a file with the following piece of code:

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] line = in.nextLine().trim().split("[ \t]");
       .
       .
       .
    }
```

When I open the file with the vim, some lines begin with the following special character:

[image]

but the java code can't read these lines. When it reaches these lines it thinks that it's the end of the file and hasNextLine() function returns false!!

EDIT: this is the hex dump of the mentioned (problematic) line:

0000000: e280 9c20 302e 3230 3133 3220 302e 3231  ... 0.20132 0.21
0000010: 3431 392d 302e 3034 0a                   419-0.04.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes The zero byte is not an end-of-file byte.  No Reader or Scanner will stop when reading it.

Comment: My guess is that one or more of the special characters are bytes with their highest bit set, which constitutes an invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.  (`new Scanner(new File(fileName))` will read the file using the system’s default charset, which is UTF-8 on most non-Windows systems.)  Print the value of `in.ioException()` after your loop finishes.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue as posted, or to reproduce what vim is showing. Can you please include a hex dump or base64 encoded snippet of the file content instead of a screenshot?

Comment: @VGR actually no exception occurs if I use hasNextLine(), but if I try to read the line without checking its existence I will get the following exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Comment: @that other guy :  I added a hex dump of the problematic line to the question!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@VGR got it right.

tl;dr: Use `Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName), "ISO-8859-1");`

What appears to be happening is that:

- Your file is not valid UTF-8 due to that lone 0x9C character.
- The Scanner is reading the file as UTF-8 since this is the system default
- The underlying libraries throw a `MalformedInputException`
- The Scanner catches and hides it (a well meaning but misguided design decision)
- It starts reporting that it has no more lines
- You won't know anything's gone wrong unless you actually ask the Scanner

Here's a MCVE:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(args[0]), args[1]);
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
      String line = in.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Line: " + line);
    }
    System.out.println("Exception if any: " + in.ioException());
  }
}
```

Here's an example of a normal invocation:

```
$ printf 'Hello\nWorld\n' > myfile && java Test myfile UTF-8
Line: Hello
Line: World
Exception if any: null
```

Here's what you're seeing (except that you don't retrieve and show the hidden exception). Notice in particular that no lines are shown:

```
$ printf 'Hello\nWorld \234\n' > myfile && java Test myfile UTF-8
Exception if any: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
```

And here it is when decoded as ISO-8859-1, a decoding in which all byte sequences are valid (even though 0x9C has no assigned character and therefore doesn't show up in a terminal):

```
$ printf 'Hello\nWorld \234\n' > myfile && java Test myfile ISO-8859-1
Line: Hello
Line: World
Exception if any: null
```

If you're only interested in ASCII data and don't have any UTF-8 strings, you can simply ask the scanner to use `ISO-8859-1` by passing it as a second parameter to the `Scanner` constructor:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName), "ISO-8859-1");
```